# Angular 2 is taking 14 sec to load after every refresh

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 RC-5, when I load the screen for first time or when I refresh it. It is taking a lot of time to load the page. Is it because it is a single page app.

I am using system.js for the package

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'webjars/rxjs/5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'webjars/angular2-in-memory-web-api/0.0.15',
    '@angular/common':            'webjars/angular__common/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/compiler':           'webjars/angular__compiler/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/forms':            'webjars/angular__forms/0.3.0',
    '@angular/core':             'webjars/angular__core/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/http':            'webjars/angular__http/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'webjars/angular__platform-browser/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'webjars/angular__platform-browser-dynamic/2.0.0-rc.5',
    '@angular/router': 'webjars/angular__router/3.0.0-rc.1',
    '@angular/router-deprecated': 'webjars/router-deprecated/2.0.0-rc.2'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
  ];
  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

[image]

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Set the base href -->
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<base href="/">
<title>TIPS</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/datatables/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/nvd3/1.8.4/build/nv.d3.css" type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="webjars/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/reflect-metadata/0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/nvd3/1.8.4/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/data/stream_layers.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js">
</script>
<script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <tips-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </tips-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are a hundred different things that could cause a page to take time loading.  What are you doing when the app initializes?  Any DB queries, service calls, or anything like that.  How large is the app?  Are you pulling in anything from external sources such as through a CDN?  What's your page like?  Is it loaded with stuff such as animations or anything?  How have you optimized your files?  Are you bundling/minifying everything you can?

Comment: Including html and js it is 2.8 MB, yes I am pulling some js files from CDN, no animations. Any suggestions on how to bundle the files.

Comment: You'll need to look at Webpack, Browserify, the Angular-CLI stuff like that to bundle it up.  But I wouldn't expect 2.8MB to be that big of a deal, especially if you are running it locally.  There's probably something else that's making it take a while.  I would look at any service calls or anything you're doing synchronously that maybe causing the delay

Comment: I added the index.html , do you think any of the importing script is causing problem.

Comment: So it looks like you're pulling the `jquery.dataTables.min.js` twice, once from the CDN once from the `webjars` directory, but that's minor.  The thing that stands out to me is your `buttons.flash.min.js` and `buttons.html5.min.js` CDN links that look like they are bad, if it's trying to resolve that, it could spin for a little while before erroring out.